# Django channels image saving, TextField or ImageField

Tags: django, django-channels

Chat app using django channels

I am using websockets to send base64 encoded string to the server, the base64 encoded string could be saved in `TextField` or saved in `ImageField` by decoding using `base64` library, which method is preferred, why?

### EDIT

I am interested in which method is preferred and why, but not how to implement

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this function for converting base64 data that you get from your request into django contentfile which can be added to image model field later**

```py
import base64
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

def base64_file(data, name=None):
    _format, _img_str = data.split(';base64,')
    _name, ext = _format.split('/')
    if not name:
        name = _name.split(":")[-1]
    return ContentFile(base64.b64decode(_img_str), name='{}.{}'.format(name, ext))

# Simple example
data = request.GET.get('base64data')
data = base64_file(data, name='profile_picture')
UserProfile.profile_picture = data
UserProfile.save()
```